# For a pandas dataframe column, TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, numpy

here is the code where 'LoanAmount', 'ApplicantIncome', 'CoapplicantIncome' are type objects:

```
document=pandas.read_csv("C:/Users/User/Documents/train_u6lujuX_CVtuZ9i.csv")


document.isnull().any()
document = document.fillna(lambda x: x.median())

for col in ['LoanAmount', 'ApplicantIncome', 'CoapplicantIncome']:
    document[col]=document[col].astype(float)

document['LoanAmount_log'] = np.log(document['LoanAmount'])
document['TotalIncome'] = document['ApplicantIncome'] + document['CoapplicantIncome']
document['TotalIncome_log'] = np.log(document['TotalIncome'])
```

i get the following error in converting the object type to float:

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number
```

please help as i need to train my classification model using these features. here's a snippet of the csv file -

```
Loan_ID Gender  Married Dependents  Education   Self_Employed   ApplicantIncome CoapplicantIncome   LoanAmount  Loan_Amount_Term    Credit_History  Property_Area   Loan_Status 
LP001002    Male    No  0         Graduate        No                5849            0                               360                        1                Urban           Y 
LP001003    Male    Yes 1         Graduate        No                4583            1508                128         360                        1                Rural           N 
LP001005    Male    Yes 0         Graduate        Yes               3000            0                   66          360                        1                Urban           Y 
LP001006    Male    Yes 0         Not Graduate    No                2583            2358                120         360                        1                Urban           Y
```

Comment: can you add the snippet of csv file ? and the line number of the error

Comment: added! @Bharathshetty

Comment: @Bharathshetty the error is during the fitting of training data in classifier

Comment: Its because of lambda in fillna didi

Answer (score 0):

In your code `document = document.fillna(lambda x: x.median())` will return a function not a value so a function cannot be converted to a float it should be either a string of numbers or an integer.

Hope the following code helps

```
median = document['LoanAmount'].median()
document['LoanAmount'] = document['LoanAmount'].fillna(median) # Or document = document.fillna(method='ffill')
for col in ['LoanAmount', 'ApplicantIncome', 'CoapplicantIncome']:
    document[col]=document[col].astype(float)

document['LoanAmount_log'] = np.log(document['LoanAmount'])
document['TotalIncome'] = document['ApplicantIncome'] + document['CoapplicantIncome']
document['TotalIncome_log'] = np.log(document['TotalIncome'])
```

Comment: Now the following error comes up-    ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float32').

Comment: Since you have lot of columns it's better to use `ffill` and then fit the data.

Comment: Actually the error is in the line where i'm fitting my classifier